# Select2 : How to get only current selected value

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Select2 returning `abs`,`def`,`ghi` values.
How to get only current selected value or data attributes.
I wants to get only `abc` or `def` which ever is selected then how could do ?

In short

i am  selecting multiple then latest selected will show.

```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.0/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.0/select2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var target = $("#e1");
            var initId = $(target).select2();       
            $(target).change(function() {
                var theID = $(target).select2();
                alert(theID);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <select id="e1" multiple >
        <option value="abc" data-id='1' >ABC</option>
        <option value="def" data-id='2'>DEF</option>
        <option value="ghi" data-id='3'>GHI</option>
        <option value="jkl" data-id='4'>JKL</option>
        <option value="mno" data-id='5'>MNO</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I still don't get it, but `$("option").each(fn)` where fn will recieve option element is not enough ?

Comment: @Deeptechtons please add your ans i wants to try ..:)

Comment: Your requirement is if you are selecting multiple then latest seleced will show am I right?

Comment: Please use given solution it will give you current selected value. I don't have time to implement complete solution right now

Answer (score 2):

If anybody's still looking for something to make this work with select2 multiple, here's how I do it :

```
$(".select2-enabler").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
  id = evt.params.data.id;
  console.log(id); //Do what you want with this
});
```

So, for my personal use case as an example, I keep the order that things were selected in the select2 plugin in a data-order attribute, here's the full code, if it can help someone (see [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b69xwxp9/) for live example):

```
$(".select2-enabler").select2(); //Enable select2 plugin

$(".select2-enabler").on("select2:select", function(evt) {

  newArr = [evt.params.data.id];
  data = $(this).data("order");
  arr = tryParseJSON(data);
  if (arr) {
    newArr = arr.concat(newArr);
  }
  $(this).data("order", JSON.stringify(newArr));
  //For demonstration purpose only
  $("#result").val($(this).data("order"));

}).on("select2:unselect", function(evt) {

  data = tryParseJSON($(this).data("order"));
  index = $.inArray(evt.params.data.id, data);
  if (!!~index) { //Bitwise flip, so that -1 == false
    data.splice(index, 1);
  }
  $(this).data("order", JSON.stringify(data));
  //For demonstration purpose only
  $("#result").val($(this).data("order"));

});

//Helper function for ParseJSON, optional
function tryParseJSON(jsonString) {
  try {
    var o = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    if (o && typeof o === "object") {
      return o;
    }
  } catch (e) {}
  return false;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below given JS i think it will work in your solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var target = $("#e1");

            $(target).change(function() {
                var latest_value = $("option:selected:first",this).val();
                alert(latest_value);

            });
        });
```

"http://jsfiddle.net/GEHUD/651/"

Please let me know if this solution not work

Comment: with your ans problem again..

getting : abc,abc ghi,abc ghi jkl

Comment: Your requirement is if you are selecting multiple then latest seleced  will show am I right?

Comment: yes same we can say. it is the part of my requirement.

Comment: In this nothing related with select2.js and nothing customization, it's simple JQuery code

Answer (score 1):

You will have to loop through the selected options of the dropdown and then add them to internal array to use it later in your code

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/GLrN7/

**Code**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnOutput").on("click", function () {
            var x = [];
            $("#ddlItems > option:selected").each(function (index, el, list) {
                x.push(el.getAttribute("data-id"));
            });

            alert(x);

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/platypusman/xDUUg/) link this will give you the answer. also you can test

You can get id/text using following way

```
var theID = $(test).select2('data').id;
var theSelection = $(test).select2('data').text;
```

[Click here for working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/platypusman/GEHUD/)

```
var selections = $('#e1').val();
alert(selections);
```

Comment: getting blank means no id getting from your ans.

Comment: i have already Google for this problem. and also tried already this fiddle.:)

Comment: is it possible for you to paste the complete code ?? i mean what exactly you want...

Comment: with your ans problem again.. getting : abc,abc ghi,abc ghi jkl

Comment: Yogesh Sharma is correct this is the correct way and you will get the selected Id in comma separated way so you can split that string with comma(,) and get the selected Id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var theID = $("option:selected", target).data("id");
```

Comment: sorry to say but same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$eventSelect.on("change", function (e) { 
    alert( $(this).val() );

})
```